# How can I make an array from a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have values from a text file and from the mySQL database I would like to compare:

Here are the values I get from the text file:

```
foreach($list as $row) {
      echo $row['cat']."<br>";
}
```

My result:

```
A2345
B7890
```

Here are the values from my database:

```
$sql = "SELECT cat FROM animals WHERE id = '$id'";                  
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo $row['cat']."<br>";
}
```

the result:

```
A2345
B7890
```

So far everything looks fine.

---

Now my problems:

To compare database content and text file content I would like to store these two results each in an array and compare them.

So my aim is to get for both sources the following result:

```
array(2) {
  ["cat"]=>
  string(5) "A2345"
  ["cat"]=>
  string(5) "B7890"
}
```

So at the end I could write:

```
If (array1 == array2) { echo "The content of database and textfile match" }
```

And here comes my problem. I do not know how to achieve it. Because if I write...

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump ($list);
echo "</pre>";
```

...I will get this result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    string(5) "A2345"
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "tom"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    string(5) "B7890"
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "sam"
  }
}
```

And if I write this...

```
echo "<pre>";
    var_dump ($list["cat"]);
    echo "</pre>";
```

...I will get:

```
NULL
```

And also with getting the database result into in array is a huge problem for me.

I wrote:

```
foreach ($pdo->query($test) as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

But my result is:

```
  array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["cat"]=>
        string(32) "A2345"
        [0]=>
        string(32) "A2345"
      }
    }
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["cat"]=>
        string(32) "A2345"
        [0]=>
        string(32) "A2345"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["cat"]=>
        string(32) "B7890"
        [0]=>
        string(32) "B7890"
      }
    }
```

I am sorry that I am so confused about what to do, but I am grateful for every hint.

Comment: you don't need to suck the entire db into php just to compare it against the file. all you'd need is to figure out how many values are in your file, and check if they're all in the db. e.g. 3 values, do `select count(*) from ... where values in (val1, val2, val3)`, if the count comes back as `3`, you know they're all there.

Comment: @Marc: I need to compare the strings. So if there is an error with "A2345" in the textfile like for example "A234?" then I need an error message

Comment: Note that what you are aiming for (the structure of the array) won't be possible since you'll be replacing keys' values. Once you set `["cat"]=>
  "A2345"`, if you try setting `["cat"]=> "B7890"`, it will replace the first value (`A2345`) with `B7890`. About the result from the query, since it seems like you are using PDO, with [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) you can get result without the `column` index.

Comment: @FirstOne: I am wondering that with `echo` I get the result I wish. I get the same values from the text file then from the database. I just need them to compare. Is it possible to create an array from the result?

Comment: When you run `foreach($list as $row) {`, it's looping the numeric index (`0`,`1`), only then you are able to access the desired key. Is the key always going to be `cat`?

Comment: @FirstOne: Yes I only need to compare `cat`

Comment: @FirstOne: I found a solution, I will edit my question

Comment: @Jarla, if you have the answer, don't edit your question, post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution I can work with:

for the text file:

```
$cat = array();
       foreach($list as $row) {
              $cat[] = $row['cat'];
        }
var_dump($cat);
```

and for the database:

```
$cat = array();
  foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
      $cat[] = $row['cat'];
    }

var_dump($cat);
```

So for both I get the result:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> string(5) "A2345" 
[1]=> string(5) "B7890" 
}
```

Now I have two arrays I can compare!

Comment: I'd be careful with the above code. By the looks of it, you are using `$cat` for both arrays. You could be overwriting the variable if this code is used in sequence!